# how to test login performance using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Im new to Jmeter and would like to know more on login performance testing. I have tried to use parameter with value in HTTP Request Defaults and try to record the login using BlazeMeter from chrome, save as jmx format and import into Jmeter. But still Jmeter unable to run the login performance. Could someone help in this matter.

I used Jmeter and follow the instructions. I have set Http Request Defaults, HTTP Cookie Manager, HTTP Cache Manager. Is there anything else i shall set?

Thank you and hope to hear from the team soon.

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded script without performing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters.

Modern web applications heavily rely on dynamic data for various reasons like [client-side state tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb386448(v=vs.100)), [security](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf) and so on.

The easiest way of detecting the dynamic parameters is recording the same scenario twice and comparing resulting .jmx test scripts. All parameters which differ are a subject to correlation.

1. Identify the dynamic parameters
2. Use suitable [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract them from previous responses and save them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
3. Replace recorded hard-coded values with the JMeter Variables from previous step

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

in JMETER to make a jmx you need :

- HTTP Request Defaults
- HTTP Cookie Manager
- Thread Group

- in Thread Group :

  - Recording Controller
- in Recording Controller :

  - Transaction Controller
- in Transaction Controller :

  - HTTP Request

for your report you need :

- View Result Tree
- Summary Report